# Azure Kubernetes Service: Cant deploy with YAML file

Tags: azure-aks

I am currently trying to setup a kube pod on a private Kubernetes cluster that i have set up on Azure Kubernetes service

However when i try to deploy it through "Add with YAML" i get an error saying
"**Failed to create the pod** failed to create to create the pod 'name-of-pod'. Error:(599): unable to reach the api server or api server is too busy to respond. Failed to fetch."
(The error switched between error 500 and error 20)

We have our own private docker container storage on azure which i am pulling from

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: name-of-pod
  namespace: 
spec:
  containers:
    - name: name
      image:image-name:master
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: secret-name
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you do not added much information, i will try my best to point you in a direction:

when you have a private AKS cluster, you can create, modify or update the cluster itself through the Azure api, but you can not create, modify or update anything inside the cluster as the API server is not accessible from outside.

An easy solution would be to create a so called `jumphost` in the same virtual network where the AKS cluster is part of. From here you could use Azure CLI and kubectl to create your pod.

As you mentioned a private docker registry, note that you would also need further Private DNS and Privat Endpoint configurations.

Comment: Alright i think i understand what you're getting at, i just thought that i would be able to use the Get started -> Create a deployment from the Azure Dashboard. 

Currently i am mostly interacting with my AKS cluster through powershell with the 
 az aks command invoke -g "resource group" -n "kubernetes service name"

But i have jumped into the deep end of the pool without learning to swim first with all this Kubernetes haha

But thanks for the advice of the Jumphost, ill look into that

Comment: Also, There is this url https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/aks/command-invoke.md
Which has details on applying yaml files on private aks cluster with command-invoke as --file attachment.